# Two classes and one method with different implementation for each of them

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, extends

I'm just starting to learn OOP in Java, so this might be a dumb question. The Cat class extends Animal, they have a constructor, a static array, a method that fills the array, and a method that creates an object of the Moving class. On this created object of class Moving, the walk() method can be invoked. Question: how to write different behavior in the walk () method, depending on how the object was created (who was the creator Animal or Cat)? I was thinking of writing a separate efficiency() method to use in the walk() method, and put it in the Animal class and override this method in the Cat class. But in the walk() method, I can only use the static method of the Animal class and I can't override it for the Cat class.

If in Main I create Animal noName = new Cat(), then the program should call Cat.efficiency(). If I create Animal noName = new Animal(), then the Animal.efficiency() method must be called. Something like this, I think. Is it possible?

```
public class Animal {
    private int capacity;
    public static int[] animalArray;

    public Animal(int value) {
        animalArray = new int[value];
    }

    public boolean adSteps(int element){
        if (capacity >= animalArray.length) {
            return false;
        } else {
            animalArray[capacity++] = element;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Moving letsMove() {
        return new Moving();
    }
    public static int efficiency(int steps){
        int equalSteps = steps+10;
        return equalSteps;
    }
}



public class Cat extends Animal{
    public Cat(int value) {
        super(value);
    }
    public static int efficiency(int steps) {
        int equalSteps = steps + 50;
        return equalSteps;
    }
}



public class Moving {
    private int[] movingArray = Animal.animalArray.clone();
    private int totalWay;
    
    public int walk(){
        System.out.println("Go ahead");
        for (int i = 0; i < movingArray.length; i++){
            totalWay += movingArray[i];
        }
        totalWay = Animal.efficiency(totalWay);
        return totalWay;
    }
}



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Animal noName = new Cat(3);

        noName.adSteps(5);
        noName.adSteps(3);
        noName.adSteps(2);

        Moving iAmMoving = noName.letsMove();

        System.out.println(iAmMoving.walk());
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use static scope

Comment: See this fantastic video on YouTube about that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpuH7n9VOYk

Comment: You example has a strange dependency graph, I think you have too much static (implicit) dependencies between your classes and that you should make those dependencies explicit, either through constructor arguments or through method call arguments (depends of the use case). That will allow you to write code that is easier to understand and will also allow you to use the inheritance (overriding methods). This answer tries to explain [how to decide when to use a static method or a static field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/when-to-use-static-methods).

Comment: Thanks to everybody for help! The task is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Overriding the `efficiency` method

If you want to be able to override your `efficiency` method in a subclass (in the `Cat` class), you need to make it an instance method instead of a `static` method.

So you would remove the `static` keyword from the `efficiency` method in the `Animal` class

```java
public class Animal {
    // ...

    public int efficiency(int steps) {
        int equalSteps = steps + 10;
        return equalSteps;
    }
}
```

You would do the same in the `Cat` class but here you would also add the `@Override` annotation

```java
public class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    public int efficiency(int steps) {
        int equalSteps = steps + 50;
        return equalSteps;
    }
}
```

Now the compiler will start complaining that the `Moving` class cannot access `efficiency` because the method cannot be called as a static method anymore. Now the `Moving` class needs an instance of the `Animal` class to be able to call the `efficiency` method.

```java
public class Moving {
    private int[] movingArray = Animal.animalArray.clone();
    private int totalWay;
    // Add an instance field to store the reference
    private Animal animal;

    // Add a constructor to pass the reference
    public Moving(Animal animal) {
        this.animal = animal; // store it here to use it later
    }

    public int walk(){
        System.out.println("Go ahead");
        for (int i = 0; i < movingArray.length; i++){
            totalWay += movingArray[i];
        }
        // use the reference here to be able to call the method
        totalWay = animal.efficiency(totalWay);
        return totalWay;
    }
}
```

And now the compiler will complain that `new Moving()` is not a constructor anymore, so you have to do another change

```
public Animal {
    // ...
    public Moving letsMove() {
        return new Moving(this);
    }
    // ...
}
```

#### Potential issue: Static storage for instance related data?

Using a static array `animalArray` (to which all `Animal` instances are adding values) to store data that belongs to each individual `Animal` instance won't produce correct results when calculating total steps for each `Animal`.

With your current example code it will work as you probably expect it to, but as soon as you will create another `Animal` instance (or another `Cat` instance) you will probably get unexpected results.

If your goal is to hold/store state that belongs to an instance, you want to use a non-static field for that. You would do the same as shown above for the `efficiency` method. Remove the `static` keyword from the `animalArray` field and change the code where it is accessed to use instance access instead of static access.

It seems the array is storing steps, so it would be less confusing if it would be called `stepsArray` instead of `animalArray`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is so simple and geniously at one time! In my previous attempts to resolve this task I tried to use non static methods too, but I didn't use word "this" like an argument when I invoked a constructor... Like a result, I didn't understand how to show, that it is an instance of one class not another.
You are absolutely right in this task I have only one instace of class and it is a reason why it works correct even with static array. This code it is a simplify version of my task without additional restrictions and conditions. Thank you for your answer, it was very useful!